# Where can I find QtMobility package for downloading?

Tags: qt, qt-mobility

I cannot find package of QtMobilty, all links that I found in internet were invalid. Could you please help? I need to install it under Windows(I need QtConnectivity library).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try [QtMobility@gitorious](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-mobility)?

Although you can't really "install" it - you will have to build it.

Answer (score 2):

http://qt.digia.com/Product/Qt-Add-Ons/Mobility/

> Qt Mobility is available as part of the Qt SDK for Nokia Devices. Get
>   it [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/Qt/Getting_started/).

Comment: This link is for the entire Qt SDK - which is the entire framework and the supporting toolchain. Not to mention it is an old outdated version.